# A caught Typescript custom error cannot be checked for its type

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I created a custom typescript error, which based on several sources seems to go like this:

```
export class Exception extends Error {

    constructor(public message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'Exception';
        this.message = message;
        this.stack = (<any>new Error()).stack;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
    }
}

export class SpecificException extends Exception {

}
```

In my code I then throw this using a simple:

```
 throw new SpecificException('foo');
```

And elsewhere I catch it:

```
catch (e) {
  var t1 = Object.getPrototypeOf(e);
  var t2 = SpecificException.prototype;

  if (e instanceof SpecificException) {
    console.log("as expected");
  }
  else {
     console.log("not as expected");
  }
}
```

This code prints "not as expected". Any ideas why?

**Later edit**

As @basarat points out bellow, the error is of the expected type. Upon further investigation I realised that this was due to a module duplication having to do with my environment, possibly because of using mocha in watch mode.

Comment: Are you sure? For me both `e instanceof Exception` and `e instanceof SpecificException` are true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran the following code:

```
declare global {
    interface Error {
        stack: any;
    } 
}
class Exception extends Error {

    constructor(public message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'Exception';
        this.message = message;
        this.stack = (<any>new Error()).stack;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
    }
}
class SpecificException extends Exception {

}

try {
  throw new SpecificException('foo');   
}
catch (e) {
  var t1 = Object.getPrototypeOf(e);
  var t2 = SpecificException.prototype;

  if (e instanceof SpecificException) {
    console.log("as expected");
  }
  else {
     console.log("not as expected");
  }
}
```

Got the desired outcome:

```
as expected
```

So there is no bug posted in the asked question